# Hedge fund memos

Tags: education

I am trying to gain some new ways of thinking about the markets via the memos published by funds or individual investors/economists. In particular, I have found insights by [BlackRock](https://www.blackrock.com/us/individual/insights) very informative.

Besides this, what sites have the best insights about global macro or finance? Is there also a place that consolidates the top memos? Open to suggestions!

Comment: Many good answers can be given so making this Community Wiki.

Comment: AQR is pretty good, Bridgewater (although they are not always published) ... and many others

Comment: Do you mind listing out some of the ones you regularly read (as you mentioned "many others")?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is my list of good research published by hedge funds / asset managers that are easily accessible.

AQR: https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Research/

Two Sigma: https://www.twosigma.com/insights/type/research/

Bridgewater: https://www.bridgewater.com/research-and-insights (they also have a famous daily newsletter that's not generally accessible)

Lord Abbett https://www.lordabbett.com/en/perspectives/weekly-fixed-income-update.html (click on "perspectives" for more sections)

GSAM: https://www.gsam.com/content/gsam/us/en/advisors/market-insights/gsam-insights/fixed-income-macro-views/global-fixed-income-weekly.html

Wellington: https://www.wellington.com/en/insights-asset-class/fixed-income/

PGIM: https://www.pgim.com/thought-leadership

Pimco: https://www.pimco.com/en-us/insights/

State Street: https://www.statestreet.com/ideas/publications.html

Blackstone: https://www.blackstone.com/insights/

Rayond James: https://www.raymondjames.com/commentary-and-insights/economy-policy/

Charles Schwab: https://www.schwab.com/resource-center/insights/category/fixed-income

TIAA Nuveen: https://www.nuveen.com/en-us/thinking

The sell side sometimes publishes excellent research, but generally don't make it freely available. (You have to have a relationship or pay for it) Generally only a few articles are freely available.

Citi GPS: https://www.citivelocity.com/citigps/

JPMorgan: https://www.jpmorgan.com/global/insights

Morgan Stanley: https://www.morganstanley.com/im/en-us/institutional-investor/insights.html

Wells Fargo: https://www.wellsfargo.com/investment-institute/weekly-market-commentary/

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure following funds' or advisors' white papers is a so great idea since they may be biased to promote one vision on the way the markets operate. For instance, remember that Blackrock has been vocal about the need for a standardisation of corporate bonds few years ago (see [FT in 2014](https://www.ft.com/content/22dfd2c2-4f01-11e4-a1ef-00144feab7de)). It is (in my opinion) a good direction, nevertheless it is certain that more standardisation reduces the cost of operation for such large asset managers.

A good option is

- select a subset of publications written by researchers from funds that are published in academic peer-reviewed journals (not journals owned by publishers with funds as main clients; I am talking about really standard, classical publishers like Wiley, Springer or World Scientific)
- look at papers published by public or independent agencies, like the ESMA, the IMF, etc.

For good entry points on the authors' side, I would suggest to follow academic papers written by [Andrea Frazzini (AQR)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/cf_dev/AbsByAuth.cfm?per_id=384604), [Jean-Philippe Bouchaud (CFM)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/cf_dev/AbsByAuth.cfm?per_id=74614), or [Thierry Roncalli (Amundi)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/cf_dev/AbsByAuth.cfm?per_id=903940). On organisations' side, [ESMA Risk Dashboards](https://www.esma.europa.eu/databases-library/esma-library/%22risk%20dashboard%22) are commenting the state of the market, [yearly IMF Global Financial Stability Reports](https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/GFSR) are great (you can read previous years reports since topics are different each time), [Bank for International Settlements (BIS) quarterly reports](https://www.bis.org/publ/qtrpdf/r_qt0309.htm) are nice too.